# How to specify only certain FaultExceptions to be Passed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, exception, faultexception

I have a WCF service and there is a CustomFaultException class inheriting from FaultException.

I have set the below code:

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
```

But it always returns the Exception with full stack trace details.

How to configure or implement a WCF Service so that only returns certain types of Exceptions e.g. CustomFaultException?

Thanks

Comment: As far as i know, WCF does not include exception details by default, so you must have some code or configuration which activates sending of exception details to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following attribute to your Service Operation:

```
[FaultContract(typeof(CustomFaultException))]
```

Within your catch, add the following:

```
throw new CustomFaultException("Custom Fault Message");
```

This will prevent the full stack trace exception details from being sent to the client.

Comment: I should point out that using exception classes in fault contracts is *not* best practice. However, it correctly answers the question, so +1.